# How can I put GNN and CNN together?

Tags: neural-networks, conv-neural-network, graph-neural-network

I am trying to combine GNN and CNN in my model.

Every node of my graph has 2d space coordinates, so as a whole it's like an irregular 2d mesh.

I think we can't use deep GNNs due to oversmoothing. So I am thinking of sampling this 2d mesh into a regular one so that I can use CNNs.

So the first part of the model is a GNN, whose information is finally aggregated into a new four-node rectangle.

Then I create an image from this rectangle. All pixels are linearly interpolated from the four nodes.

Finally come the CNNs.

What I am not sure is that, my image is created according to the four nodes, but it does not contain gradient information. Also, my convolution kernels are not directly related to the former four-nodes. I am afraid that the path of gradients is blocked.

So how can I put these two parts together to make an unblocked model, and the gradients can propagate without problem?

Comment: Can you describe how your GNN generates a four-node rectangle and what are your features in the original graph's nodes?

Comment: @gunes It's just a primeval thought. I think maybe GCN on the original graph, and then find a good aggregation method to these four nodes. The graph part and the features are not fixed yet. Now what I am worried about is, how can the tensors go from this rectangle (or square) to a image and then CNN, while back propagation still works. Because I am not good at the underlying mathematical principle of neural networks.